# What is best way to manage database in ONE CMS/MULTIPLE WEBSITE system

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4.1

I'm developing content management system (CMS). But this different from other CMS. I can maintain one CMS and define content to multiple website. Like a Blog. But some website has different tables.

My current CMS has one database (MS SQL 2005)

Database include lot of tables:

Main tables

- User
- Page
- Modules
- Portals
  etc...

Web 1 tables

- web1Post
- web1CustomTable
- web1Table2
  etc...

Web 2 tables

- web2Customtable3
- web2CustomTable4
- web2Table4
  etc...

Every custom tables joined User, Portal and other some tables. This is successfully works.

But i want to separate database to MainDatabase, web1database, web2database etc...

I'm trying to separate database. But problem is User, Portal and connected tables has problem

I'm using EntityFramework, Asp.net MVC

What is best way to solve this?

Comment: This is a common problem but I don't know any particular solution would quite qualify as "the best solution" without further explanation of the problem each solution was trying to solve.. that is, many solutions (esp. after the second or third try) might be considered "the best" for that particular situation. You might want to consider asking for reasonable solutions instead of the "best" one.

Answer (score 3):

There is no “best” way to solve this. Just separate the databases and then start working on fixing the code in your application.

You’d need to

- create entity framework mappings for new databases
- update code and remove references to existing database
- add new code with references to new databases

However, I’d recommend that you don’t separate the databases but make changes in your existing schema to support customizations.  Maybe you can use xml columns  to store custom data or even create your application layer so that it can update database structure dynamically. This is how TFS and Dynamics CRM handle customizations – they have main schema in database and metadata shcema that stores info about customizations.

Comment: Looking at how TFS and Microsoft Dynamics CRM do this is probably a good start as they both allow limited but useful extensibility.

Answer (score 2):

Download and install the Kentico CMS and explore how it tackles this problem. If you want to have a multi-tenant database define/replicate a different schema for each tenant/website.

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve a problem of related tables from different databases.
Do not create the database for individual sites, such SharePoint does not create a databases for subwebs. Just create a foreign key in each table of subweb, for example SubwebId.
When you decide to have separate databases, you will have to create a stored procedure for generation of a subweb databases, method for creating a Web site under IIS (also need to bind domain to a subweb), method of generating site files from a template by replacing all connection strings. Do you really want to do it? I think this is not a good idea. (Sory for bad English)

Comment: The multi-tenant problem is quite common and often solved with multiple databases. You're making quite a few assumptions about how these databases would be deployed.  The best reasons for going with a multiple database solution is that once the tenant is gone, the database and data associated is simply archived and *removed*. Using separate databases affords a lot of flexibility.

Comment: I think that the data deletion is a last resort and with the volume and cost of the storage systems is not very relevant. Furthermore, deletion of data in some systems, is harmful,  for example, on Facebook.

Comment: It's quite relevant when a single tenant's data can grow into hundreds of gigabytes as I've seen. When data grows that large, there are quite a few performance considerations as well.  With such large databases, it makes sense to have dedicated servers, not just dedicated databases.  And if the tenant leaves, well, that is just more resources freed up.

Answer (score 0):

From your description so far, it feels like to me you have one CMS-Database and several related websites.  You could use SCHEMAs to separate the data for the separate sites.  So, you could use the [dbo] schema for the tables that relate to all the sites.  And then [website1] for the tables that are specific to website1 and so forth.

Individual databases should be mostly independent of each-other.  ACID will not always work across databases.  Individual databases will have separate backup times.  Each database could be moved to a different server.  Each database could be in a different state.  You can't have a good clean reliable foreign-key relationship between databases.  As long as you require a dependency between [User] and other tables, those other tables will have to be in the same db.